# Suggestions for Real-Time Code Signing Solution

Tags: web-applications, antivirus, pfx, self-signed-certificate

I need to resolve an issue with a web based application that I support. This application generates a Win32 application on-the-fly to perform a task locally on a client workstation and downloads the app for the user to run. Anti-virus software sometimes generates a false positive in this application and blocks the user from running it.
I thought if I signed the executable before downloading it the issue would be resolved, so I found and implemented a simple signing function and used our code signing certificate to test it. I'm still not 100% positive this has fixed the anti-virus issue because it happens somewhat randomly.
With this code in place, the issue I am trying to resolve now is this: I want to distribute a non-expiring pfx certificate file with the web app so it can be used long term for this task. This is not a cloud-based web application. Customers purchase our ap and host it in their own domains, so I will not have access to hundreds of our user's systems to regularly update the certificate if it expires, and I don't want them to have to update certificates either if that can be avoided. I of course do not want to distribute our company's code signing certificate because of the potential for theft and malicious activity.
I was able to determine how to use PowerShell to easily generate a self-signed certificate in a pfx file and thought either I might be able to do it once for the web app or it might be something I could have each system's administrator do once on their system, but I am concerned that the root certificate authority is not trusted for self-signed certificates and I am not sure if anti-virus software would not still detect false positives in this scenario. Am I even barking up the right tree? I wish I knew exactly what was triggering the anti-virus software to detect a threat in the executable file in the first place, but I don't know how to find that out.